# Is ?& allowed in URL

Tags: javascript, url

I was reviewing some code and I saw something like this:

```
if (result.indexOf('?') === -1) {
    result += '?';
}
result += '&' + SOMETHING;
```

Clearly this can result in an URL like this http://example.com?&a=b

The author of the code sees nothing unusual in the code but **?&** bothers me. I could not find any restrictions in the RFC for URI to prove him wrong (or maybe I missed it).

Clearly in the network tab of Chrome dev tools it appears as an empty pair:
[image]

Should URL like this bother me or am i just paranoid?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's valid - any client I've ever seen regards it as valid, anyway. Query parameters can be single terms (`http://example.com?queryparam`) and the jump to a completely empty query parameter from there is not far.

Comment: What about it bothers you and wouldn't be valid?

Comment: @j08691: It's not unreasonable for somebody to find a query string beginning with an & unusual.

Comment: Is there a problem with that? `&` is usually used to separate key/value pairs in the query part of the URI, why are you so surprised that people are interested in an empty pair's validity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This case will be interpreted as an empty value by most servers, so yes, it is indeed valid. What's going to happen is that the server checks between `?` and every `&` and then separates the values at `=` accordingly.

So when there is nothing between a `?` and a `&` (or two `&`'s), the values will both be empty. Missing `=`'s will affect whether the value is "" or null, but it will not make the query invalid.

Watch out with this, because some parsers might not find this to be valid, so you may get problems when using custom parsers (in JavaScript for example).

Comment: I was talking about custom JavaScript, because some people might use JavaScript to parse `loaction.serach` by themselves.

Comment: I removed my previous comment as it was misleading. I'm still not sure javascript parsing is relevant in that case, but if OP's is content with this answer everything's good :)

Comment: I'll one more time try to explain my point: Some people might use client-side parsers to extract values from the location string itself (which is contained in `location.hash`). Even though the browser accepts `?&`, those parsers might not - which will lead to JavaScript errors on the client-side.

Comment: My problem is more with your opening sentence, because the question of the URI validity still stands even without JS or the browser parsing the URI. For example, OP's code generate the URI and put it in a link's `href`. For now it's only text, and when the user clicks the link it isn't parsed either, just sent to a server as the resource path in an HTTP request. So now the question is "will the non-descript server that receives that HTTP request consider it valid?" and whether the browser would does not matter.

Comment: Not that it matters really, the question is tagged `javascript`, your answer is correct on the scope it covers and was accepted by OP :)

Comment: Now I get you. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote up [a blog post](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell) about some of these edge cases years ago.

tl;dr: yes, `?&example` is valid

What's important about it is that you're defining a key of `""` with a value of `null`.

You can pretty much guarantee that almost no libraries support those empty string keys, so don't rely on them working, but as far as having a URL along the lines of `?&foo=bar`, you should be fine when accessing the `foo` key.